# Drawing a 3D multicolor triangle in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I need to make this triangle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PlIv.png) in turtle, but just can't quite get the dimensions right. In addition to this, I also need each quadrant of the triangle to display in a different color according to a list I have set... I can do that later. But I am having trouble getting the length/widths of the triangle to be correct. I will link a picture of something similar to what It needs to be here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuOgu.png) This is the closest thing I could find that resembles that I need it to do. How do I use something like `width, width * math.sqrt(2), and width` to get the lengths and widths of the triangle? Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry if my English is bad, it is not my first language. Below is what I have written so far.

```
turtle.setup(575,575)
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.pensize(2)
pen.hideturtle()

width = random.randint(25,100)

def draw_art_cube(x,y):
    draw_triangle(width, width * math.sqrt(2) + width)

def draw_triangle(x,y):
    pen.up()
    pen.setpos(x,y)
    pen.down()
    pen.setheading(0)
    pen.forward(width)
    pen.left(width)





turtle.onscreenclick(draw_art_cube)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Why does the title include **3D** when we're drawing **2D** figures?  Or is the example *.png file actually 3D but not showing up correctly on my display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `draw_triangle()` function is woefully underwritten.  You need to draw a minimum of half a dozen lines but your code only draws *one*!  Let's flesh out this function to make it draw the example image:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

def draw_art_cube(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # Disable handler inside handler

    pen.up()
    pen.setposition(x, y)
    pen.down()

    width = randint(25, 100)
    draw_triangle(width)

    screen.onscreenclick(draw_art_cube)  # Reenable handler on exit

def draw_triangle(short):

    long = short * 2**0.5

    pen.setheading(0)

    for _ in range(4):
        pen.forward(short)
        pen.left(135)
        pen.forward(long)
        pen.left(135)
        pen.forward(short)

        pen.left(180)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(575, 575)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.speed('fastest')
pen.pensize(2)

screen.onscreenclick(draw_art_cube)
screen.mainloop()
```

This drawing code is inefficient as it draws 12 (somewhat redundant) lines when we can get away with half that.  But it should give you a working starting point to think through the best way to draw this figure.